# Retaining the input of a textarea when refreshing ASP Classic page.

Tags: html, asp-classic, textarea

I am trying to retain the users inputs in a textarea on my ASP classic form, so that if the recaptcha is entered wrong then the user's input is not lost and they only have to re-enter the captcha text. I am able to retain the input from a normal text box using `value="<%=session("Address")%>"`. But the same thing does not work for textareas. I have seen a solution for PHP and so was hoping there was something available for ASP. How can i go about doing this, and if possible I would prefer to keep it server side? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how the session variable could possibly contain the *user's* input. *Your default* input, yes, but to get the user's input, you need to request it from the form (or querystring), don't you?

Comment: I tend to agree with Martha - persisting form data should be handed through the `Request` object, not the `Session`, where at all possible.

Comment: I used the request.Form to give the session variable its value. session("address") = request.Form("address"). Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so:

```
<textarea name="" id=""><%=session("Address")%></textarea>
```

Keep in mind that you should not put out user generated texts directly in your site. think of malicious JavaScript code in session("address")...

you should encode those values like so:

```
<textarea name="" id=""><%=server.htmlencode(session("Address"))%></textarea>
```

same for all other places where you "inject" user generated values in your site...

Comment: Awesome thank you. I have also gone and fixed the other places where it worked but was obviously not secure. Thanks again.